# Why isn't the Highcharts library, defined from a custom module, loaded in every page?

Tags: javascript, 9

I am running Drupal 9.1.7 on lando on a Mac.  I am writing a custom module and I want to include the Highcharts library.  The .libraries.yml file looks like this.

```yaml
stats_degrees:
  js:
    https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js: { type: external, minified: false }
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

From reading the documentation, I believe I should see the Highcharts library at the bottom of every page when I view the source, but I don't see it anywhere.

Am I missing something?

I have already validated the YAML content. I also installed the Charts module, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 2):

Defining the library is only half of the process. Libraries are not loaded on every page by default - you need to tell Drupal when it should include your library.

For full details, see the [Attaching a library to page(s)](https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-module#attaching) section of the [Adding stylesheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS) to a Drupal module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-module) documentation on drupal.org.

I bet you want to [attach the library to a render array](https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-module#render-array):

```
$build['the_element_that_needs_asset_library']['#attached']['library'][] = 'your_module/library_name';
```

Or [attach the library in a twig template](https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-module#twig) (the template that produces your chart markup):

```
{{ attach_library('your_module/library_name') }}
```

Comment: Yes!  I am trying to attach it to a render array like so:

`$chart['#attached']['library'][] = 'stats_degrees/highcharts';`
`$chart['#type']  = 'chart';`
`$chart['#chart_type'] = 'line';`
`$chart['#chart_library'] = 'highcharts';`
etc.
But when I return the array: `return render($chart);`

it is always null and there is no Highcharts JS when I view source.

This approach worked in D7 but D7 handled JS libraries differently and drupal_render() has been replaced by render().

Comment: You usually shouldn't render a render array by calling render, you should just return it. That's the first thing that I would try. See https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/twig-best-practices-preprocess-functions-and-templates

Comment: I am doing it for debugging in PHP Storm,  `$rendered = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderPlain($chart);`. When I drill into the debugger I see that Renderer::executeInRenderContext() is returning null.  There must be something amiss with my render array...  maybe we should close this thread and I will open a new one after I do more debugging.

Comment: Yeah, that seems like a good idea. It sounds like you know how to attach the library properly, but there's a problem with your render array.

Comment: I installed the highcharts library using composer.  It installed it under /libraries.  Makes sense.  How do I reference this in my .libraries.yml file?  I tried making it relative to my module `../../../libraries/highcharts/highcharts.js: {  }` but I still don't see it in the page source. I have tried attaching it to my render array and in a twig template like this: `{{ attach_library('stats_degrees/highcharts') }}` but I still don't see it.